# Microsoft Form Recognizer return 401 error

Tags: azure, azure-form-recognizer

I am trying to use Microsoft Form Recognizer API.
I get the following error returned from API call.
Please help to advice.

```
"{\r\n  \"error\": {\r\n    \"code\": \"401\",\r\n    
\"message\": \"The Analyze Layout Operation under Form Recognizer API is not supported 
with the current subscription key and pricing tier ComputerVision.S1.\"\r\n  }\r\n}"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Please create a Form Recognizer resource in the Azure Portal. The endpoint and key you are using are from a Computer Vision resource, you need the endpoint and key from a Form Recognizer resource.

Neta - MSFT